# How to set additional custom attribute in Eloquent Laravel while using Accessor

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, accessor

I'm trying to set additional custom attribute while using Accessor in Laravel model.

Example:
I'm calculating promotion price and setting this new attribute, but in additional want to set "`$promo = 1 || $promo = 0`" using the same logic.

The very cut example just with logic. The real logic is far deeper, that's why I don't want to duplicate the accessor:

```
public function getFinalPriceAttribute($value)
{

    if($this->promotion == true) {
        $final_price = $this->price * 100;
        //here I want to add new attribute (promo = 1)
        //Something like using another method here to setAttribute. Example: setPromoAttribute(1)
    } else {
        $final_price = $price;
        //here I want to add new attribute (promo = 0)
        //Something like using another method here to setAttribute. Example: setPromoAttribute(0)
    }

        return $final_price;
    }

    protected $appends = ['final_price', 'on_sale'];
}
```

I can easily duplicate the whole `getFinalPriceAttribute()`, but make no sense to have exactly the same code in two `getAttribute()` accessors. Any idea?

Comment: Are those attribute meant to be together ? Are you sure you want one accessors for both of them ?

Comment: try to update `getFinalPriceAttribute()` to set `$this->price =1` but still you will have a problem while getting value

Comment: If there is any alternative logic to be done I'm ok with it, just don't want to duplicate 100+ rows of code.
Let's say `created_at:"2018-01-03 09:40:09"
final_price:"120.00"
id:289
price:"240.00"` is example structure of 1 item of 100 in an object.
I want to add promo = 1 if price is discounted.. I can check if the two prices are != but not always this is the reason. Thats why want when I set final_price attribute to set at the same time promo = 1 attribute.

Comment: What's the problem with setting the property right there?

Comment: Just nothing happens, when I try to do
`$this->promo = 1`. Probably if I use global variable in __constructor, and  after that I change the value of this global variable in getFinalPriceAttribute Accessor and finally I do 2nd Accessor getPromoAttribute(), and there just `return $this->promo`

Comment: I would suggest moving the logic to check if it's promo or not to a dedicated function so you can re-use it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this is the correct implementation of what you want to achieve but here are two hacks:

**1.**

Create a virtual relation for this row in accessor with a new `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` and then push the item `promo` value into it. But THIS WILL BE AN ARRAY.

```
public function getFinalPriceAttribute($value)
{
    $this->setRelation('promo', new Collection());
    if($this->promotion == true) {
        $final_price = $this->price * 100;
        $this->promo->push(1);
    } else {
        $final_price = $price;
        $this->promo->push(1);
    }

    return $final_price;
}
```

So in response, you'll get `promo` as array like:

```
{
    "promotion": true,
    "promo": [
        1
    ]
}
```

or

```
{
    "promotion": false,
    "promo": [
        0
    ]
}
```

**2.**

Create two accessors for `promo`. One as `promo0` & other is `promo1` and append the attribute dynamically(and conditionally) with `append()`. But this way you'll get two different attributes in response conditionally.

```
public function getPromo1Attribute()
{
    return true;
}

public function getPromo0Attribute()
{
    return true;
}

public function getFinalPriceAttribute($value)
{
    if($this->promotion == true) {
        $final_price = $this->price * 100;
        $this->append('promo1');
    } else {
        $final_price = $price;
        $this->append('promo0');
    }

    return $final_price;
}
```

And this will return the response like:

```
{
    "promotion": true,
    "promo1": true
}
```

or

```
{
    "promotion": false,
    "promo0": true
}
```

*I hope this will help at least someone in the future.*